# MySQL Workbench doesn't install on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, package, mysql-workbench

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved

When I try to install workbench appears this error.

[image]

Comment: Error from terminal:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: mysql-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

**1#**
you could update your cache

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try to let apt-get resolve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The **-f** flag fixes broken dependencies.

**2#** Sometimes the `-f` option is not going to work for you. If it doesn't work, then you have to install the package giving an exact version. In order to do so, you can use `=` to set the version the system wants.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Ubuntu repository for MySQL Workbench:

- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

You sould use it to install MySQL Workbench.